# MVC 5 Ajax call to database returning error

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and so far I've connected my database and created a entity controller class with the default CRUD.

However, in my `Index.cshtml` I'm trying to update the database with an ajax script but I'm getting an error and I don't know where to go from there.

```
Database : MyDB

Users Table
==========================================
| Column     | Type         |            |
==========================================
| ID         | int          | Primary AI |
------------------------------------------
| Name       | varchar (50) | NULL       |
------------------------------------------
| Company    | varchar (50  | NULL       |
==========================================
```

## MyDBsController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Company")] MyDB myDB)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(myDB);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(myDB);
    }
```

### Index.cshtml

```
<script>
$('a').click(function () {
    $name = "John";
    $company = "123Moving";

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "MyDBsController")',
        data: { 'Name': $name, 'Company' : $company },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr + ajaxOptions + thrownError);
        }

    })
})
</script>
```

Error I'm getting is `[Object object] error not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST method is decorated with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute but your ajax call does not pass the token so the method is never run..

Either remove the attribute, or if you have a form that includes `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, you can pass the token using

```
var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
$.ajax({
  ....
  data: { 'Name': $name, 'Company': $company, '__RequestVerificationToken': token },
```

or better, assuming you have form controls for `Name` and `Company`, just use

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

which will serialize all the form data including the token.

In addition, as drneel as noted in the other answer, your model appears to be `User`, not `MyDB` so it would be

```
public ActionResult Create(User user)
```

Side note; It appears you want all properties of you model, so your `[Bind(Include = "..")]` attribute is a bit pointless (all properties are included by default). Having said that, an `ID` (primary key) property is not appropriate in a 'Create' method and a malicious user could easily post back an `ID` value, causing your method to fail. You should be using a view model containing only the `Name` and 'Company' properties, then map the view model properties to a new instance of the data model and save the data model. I also suggest that the `Name` property should be `NOT NULL` (and possibly the `Company` as well)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the parameter in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Company")] MyDB myDB)
```

You are trying to `POST` a `User` to a controller that takes `MyDB` which I'm guessing is your DBContext.  It should be:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Company")] User user)
```

Replace `User` with whatever your user class actually is